# Solar water-pump working continuously

Tags: solar-power, water, wind-power

I want to install a solar water-pump or a windmill water pump to extract water from an aquifer without stop during the day (constant flow). The solar water-pump is less expensive and comes with the extra feature of using solar panels I have. My question is, is it somehow bad for the battery and/or the solar pump to be running 8/10 hours a day every day? should I better consider the windmill water pump?

Comment: Why do you need batteries when you only want the water to be pumped during the day? you could consider disconnect these to spare them for another usage.

Comment: @J.Chomel I assumed the solar water-pump will require a battery (even during the day), but if that's not the case, the only question I had left is whether the electric(solar) pump will be more prone to get damaged than the windmill if it is used during long periods of time. Thanks

Comment: You say that you want to "extract water from an aquifer without stop during the day ... every day".  I'm puzzled by this.  Why would you want to ask a question about how to constantly extract water from an aquifer *on a sustainability forum*?  It strikes me that any activity requiring non-stop pumping of water from an aquifer is, by its very definition, _unsustainable_.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Tim I get what you are saying.The point is not to do it every day of every month of the year but probably a continous week (or less days) from time to time. The problem is that during dry season the water supply is a big issue and it is needed to feed some farm animals (not in a industrial kind of way) and for domestic use. I live in the countryside of a tropical country. The non-stop part comes from my (possibly wrong) understanding that solar pumps don't pump as much water in the same timespam as others(discharge rate I think is called).The goal is not to deplenish one of our water sources.

Comment: Regarding pumps, you're talking about a "100% duty cycle".  If you get one that is rated for a lower duty cycle, you will probably ruin it.  If you get one rated for 100% duty cycle, it's probably okay (at least, that's what the rating is supposed to mean).  Solar panels "run" continuously anyway and have no moving parts.  They derate over time but there's no other use you're going to put them to that's any less demanding.  Batteries wear out but it's not clear you actually need or want any in this situation.  Just use all the power you generate as you generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared to a battery an elevated water tank is the better energy storage for times without sun or wind if the energy is solely needed for water pumping. Double conversion of energy (to electricity and back to use) and loss of energy in the battery, which even will age, will waste a lot of energy and money.

Hight of water tank depends on the pressure you need to distribute the water later. In many cases it must not be very high. Which kind of "energy converter" you should use depends on the availability of wind or sun and technology.

On the country side a wind turbine may operate the water pump directly without electrical energy conversion. So it is even much easier to repair. If there is sufficient wind available that would be my preferred solution, even when it appears to be quite old fashioned.